# Calling a method from another controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 controllers (`booking` and `taxi`). I am going to call a method of `taxi` in create method of `booking`.

so i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767222/rails-call-another-controller-action-from-a-controller), and used this line

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
      def create
        redirect_to url_for(:controller => :taxis, :action => :compute) and return
    end
end
```

i add `and return` [because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590116/abstractcontrollerdoublerendererror-in-admin) i faced with erorr

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError
```

and compute method is a simple puts

```
def compute  
   puts "Address is @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"     
end
```

the problem is, when i run it, i face with this message

```
Redirected to http://agile-system-lashkarara.c9users.io:8081/compute
```

**but it puts nothing in console**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Because the 'and return' is not necesarry if you want to redirect_to somewhere in your create method.

Comment: I am expecting to run **compute** method

Comment: And if you want to do something with a Taxi in the BookingsController, you should probably create a method in the Taxi model, so you can call it directly. If you explain the required functionality I could point you in the right direction.

Comment: It's ok, if i can have the compute in my model. could you please wirte an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move compute to the Taxi model like this:

```
#model/taxi.rb
#please note that this is a class method and not an instance method!
def self.compute

  puts "Address is @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        "

end
```

Then you can call `Taxi.compute`, but this is probably not exactly what you are looking for, since you will probably need to call the method for a specific Taxi, then you don't need the self. part and you need to call the method on a ActiveRecord object of a Taxi.

Comment: and it is in model or in controller?

Comment: model, you cannot call methods from another Controller. (EDIT: you can, but you shouldn't)