# How to redirect_to in custom devise controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I have devise set up with custom controller (user controller), just like explained [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers).

I customised some of the controller logic like so

```rb
def create

  super do |user|
    @patient = user.build_patient
    @patient.save
  end

end
```

All of that works fine. The problem is when I try to provide custom `redirect_to`, then I see

```rb
def create

  super do |user|
    @patient = user.build_patient
    @patient.save
  end

  redirect_to physicians_path
end
```

[Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11591571/5783745) to the general problem of having (accidental or otherwise) > 1 `redirect_to` inside a controller won't work because i) I can't affect the first one (since its part of devise), and ii) I don't know how to tell it to ignore the first one and use the one I specify instead

Answer (score 0):

I won't accept this answer, because I'm sure there's a better way, but here's what worked anyway:

1. Copy the code from the [relevant controller](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/v4.7.3/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L46-L62) in the devise code
2. Edit it however you want
3. I didn't use `super` (I think it would be better to, but I didn't figure out how)

So I simply added this

```rb
def update

  self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
  prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

  resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource_updated
    set_flash_message_for_update(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email)
    bypass_sign_in resource, scope: resource_name if sign_in_after_change_password?

    # respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    set_minimum_password_length
    respond_with resource
  end

end
```

Note the only difference from the devise code is commenting out this

```
    # respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
```

and adding this in its place

```
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
```